# Developing mobile app for android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am developing a mobile app for android, with eclipse as my platform. 
Whenever I use the back button of the mobile using the emulator,
the app closes. I want to just go back to the previous page, but 
it exits the app. How can I do it? I really hope you could me with this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should provide at least some information about software you're using, especially the emulator. "Eclipse" is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before u start a new Activity, you should not call finish () on the current Activity
If Finish () is not called and you move to a new activity, and press BACK then you will be taken to the previous activity...

learn about the activity lifecycle, and you will understand
http://stuffthathappens.com/blog/2008/11/05/android-activity-lifecycle-updated/
http://www.anddev.org/lifecycle_of_an_activity-t81.html

Answer (score 2):

I guess you start a new activity and call `finish()` on the old one, right!? Don't do that, just start the new activity.

If that's not the case, please provide the code where you start your new activity.

Answer (score 1):

Two chance for this
1) You may use viewflipper for displaying different pages, So you have only one activity. If so u need to override onKeyDown function and set your view flipper display child as you want when the keycode is KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
2) If you are using different activities (Which is always preferred ) you may be finishing the old activity while calling new one. Then remove that code for finishing, `finish()`